# OpenVPN Specify Network Connection over similar IP range

Tags: centos, networking, ip, openvpn

I am connecting to an OpenVPN server which is working fine using my OpenVPN GUI and Certificate file. I need to connect to a Linux machine that is running on the remote OpenVPN Network.

This is no problem from my home network because I have the following

```
Internal Gateway    192.168.20.10
Remote Linux Server 192.168.1.10
```

So I can easily SSH into the server using 192.168.1.10

The problem is when I'm on a different network I end up the following

```
Internal Gateway    192.168.1.10
Remote Linux Server 192.168.1.10
```

So when I try to SSH into the remote server it is connecting to my Internal Gateway. Is it possible to specify that I want to connect to the remote IP 192.168.1.10 instead of the internal one?